# braintree payments integration with zf2( zend framework 2 )

Tags: zend-framework2, braintree

i am new to zf2 and want to integration  of  braintree payments in to my zf2 project .

i have added below lines of code in `vendor/autoload.php`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/braintree/lib' . '/autoload.php';
```

when i add Configuration code to my action it stop working and gives blank screen  ( as per my app settting error view is removed so it gives blank screen . error is class not found  )

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
```

Please help me to set up `braintree` lib in zf2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: @Maks3w its not related to white screen its not allow to add braintree payment gateway  to my zf2 application

Comment: @Maks3w check my updated question . i know what is error . its braintree class not found .

Comment: 2nd. Just remove the braintree autoloader. Not required because seems you are using the Composer's package

Comment: @Maks3w i am not able to use Composer's  package as my sever is not allow to run command line . m working direct on shared server

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can use Composer in your local machine and upload the vendor folder.

Comment: @Maks3w project is not configure  in my local machine . as m working for my client have to work directly on FTP

Comment: @Maks3w have to manually add this lib to my controller but not able to get success

Comment: @Maks3w yes but there should be a alternative that i can set up everything manually. composer is not a must .  so will find out how to work  thanks for downvote

Comment: @Maks3w check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the use of below  blog article a am able to configure braintree payment gateway lib on may server manually .

http://www.loneshooter.com/zend-framework-2-how-to-use-facebook-php-sdk/

1) Here i need to add lib reference in autoload_classmap.php like below.

```
 <?php
  return array(
    'Braintree' => 'vendor/< path to Braintree >/Braintree.php',
  );
```

2) In function getAutoloaderConfig of Module.php file add ClassMapAutoloader section if it doesn’t exist in order to load configurations from autoload_classmap.php file. The function should look as it follows:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),

        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );

}
```

3) After the changes i can use the Braintree library in your controller:

```
$Braintree = new \Braintree\Configuration();
$Braintree::merchantId('your_merchant_id');
$Braintree::publicKey('your_public_key');
$Braintree::privateKey('your_private_key');
```